# Misunderstanding of Polar Co-ordinates for Double Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the volume of a sphere using a double integral with polar co-ordinates. I don't want to simply use the polar co-ordinates formula, as I want to understand why that formula works.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
R^2=x^2+y^2+z^2 \\
z=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} \\
V=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-R}^{R} \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} dx dy \\
x=r\cos(\theta) \\
y=r\sin(\theta) \\
V=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-R}^{R} \sqrt{R^2-\left(r^2\left(\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)\right)\right)} dx dy \\ V=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-R}^{R} \sqrt{R^2-r^2}  dxdy  \\
dx=dr\cos(\theta) \\
dy=r\cos(\theta)d\theta \\
V=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-R}^{R} \sqrt{R^2-r^2}  dr\cos(\theta)r\cos(\theta)d\theta  \\
V=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-R}^{R} \sqrt{R^2-r^2}  rdrd\theta \cos^2(\theta)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Note that I have yet to change the bounds of my integral. My question is why my integral has $rdrd \theta cos^2(\theta)$ instead of $rdrd(\theta)$. I'm also not positive that my bounds are correct. I reasoned that both $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates should be from $-R$ to $R$ as that is both co-ordinates maximum values. However, upon researching this question I see varying integral bounds.

Thank-you for any help!

Comment: You might want to prefix trigonometric functions' names with a backslash. They would be rendered in upright font with proper spacing as function names (`r\sin\theta` → $r\sin\theta$) instead of italics, which look just like a multiplication of many variables (`r sin\theta` → $r sin\theta$). You could also use a thin space to separate differentials from variables (`r\,dr` → $r\,dr$ vs. `r dr` → $r dr$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial integral 
$$V=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-R}^{R} \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}\,dx\,dy$$
has the wrong bounds.

The bounds
$$-R \le x \le R$$
$$-R \le y \le R$$
define a square in the $xy$-plane of side length $2R,\;$centered at the origin.

The domain should be a disk in the $xy$-plane of radius $R,\;$centered at the origin.

A corrected version would be
$$-\sqrt{R^2-x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$$
$$-R \le x \le R$$
which yields the initial integral
$$V=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} \,dy\,dx$$
Another error is how you dealt with the substitutions
$$x = r\cos\theta$$
$$y = r\sin\theta$$
The above substitutions can be used to replace $x,y\;$in the integrand, but $dx,dy\;$can't be replaced separately, since they each depend on *both* $r$ and $\theta$.

The correct replacement is $dxdy = dA = rdrd\theta$.

In terms of $r\;$and $\theta,\;$the domain $D\;$has the bounds
$$0 \le r \le R$$
$$0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$$

The substitution then works out as follows . . .
\begin{align*}
V&=2\int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} \,dy\,dx\\[4pt]
&=2\iint_D \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}\,dA\\[4pt]
&=2\iint_D \sqrt{R^2-r^2}\,dA\\[4pt]
&=2\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R\left(\!\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right) r\,dr\,d\theta\\[4pt]
&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{R^3}{3}\,d\theta\\[4pt]
&=\bigl({\small{\frac{4}{3}}}\bigr)\pi R^3\\[4pt]
\end{align*}